# Docker local and shared network

Tags: security, docker, networking, overlay, docker-swarm

I need to set up an environment similar the one described in the following image:
[image: Done with draw.io]

As depicted in the diagram, I need to deploy in two different Virtual Machines two different applications that needs to communicate each other through private IP address. But, for security reason, is very important that the "Third parties App" cannot contact "MongoDB" and the "REST API" cannot contact "MYSQL DB".

To do this I tried the Docker Swarm and the docker stacks; unfortunately, with this approach I totally loose the control on where my services are deployed (e.g. the REST API could be deployed in the right-hand Virtual Machine).

Can someone help me in finding a way to setup this configuration?
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried already?  It seems like you’ve already made the key architectural decisions, you’ve decided to run plain Docker (not Swarm) inside two VMs and are looking for something like an Ansible setup to configure them.

Comment: I tried to create a swarm with the VM1 as master and the VM2 as worker. But deploying a stack on VM1 some containers are launched on VM2 and, anyway, this approach doesn't allow me to segregate the containers as I was expecting: in fact, the Third Parties App was able to contact the MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an e`xternal network` and use this in each stack

```
docker network create --driver=overlay --attachable your-share-network
```

Compose example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    networks:
    - your-share-network

networks:
  your-share-network:
    external: true
```

For reference check [Docker network configuration reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#network-configuration-reference)